# Default applications (GNOME 3)

Tags: fedora, gnome3

I'm trying to associate a custom application to a file type in GNOME 3 (FC15).
In GNOME 2 one could go in the "Open with" pane of the file properties dialog and add a custom command there. The custom command edit box seems to have disappeared from the "Open with" pane in GNOME 3, so I was wondering if there is some workaround to manually assign the application.

In other words, from which file/directory does GNOME pull out that application list? How do I add a custom one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is the answer:
http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=263501

I have Gnome3 and there is "Open with" pane :) You also go to proporties and there is "Open with" tab.

Edit:
You should look on https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=118966. Your applications should show on list, if you add a *.desktop file associated with your application to /usr/share/applications or ~.local/share/applications/ directory. Exec should like this:
    Exec=yourprogram %U

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that is not what I am asking. I know that there is an "Open with" pane, what is missing is the "custom command" edit box. I will rephrase my question accordingly

Comment: Seems to work fine, I'll still have to figure out a couple of things but it does the job. Thank you

Comment: Please don't answer with just a link. At the least, summarize the solution in the body of your answer. You can link for further reading, but that is not a substitute for providing an inline answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

I know this is late but...Fist, create a desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications/` for example `sublime.desktop` would be something like *~/.local/share/applications/sublime.desktop* with the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Keywords=Plaintext;Write;Programming;Syntax;Ruby;HTML
Categories=;
Comment=sublime
Exec=sublime_text %U
Hidden=false
Icon=icon-name
Name=sublime
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Version=1.0
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=text/plain;text/html;application/ruby;
```

Then... if you edit `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` you will see the content type *text/html* edit it like so:

```
[Default Applications]
x-scheme-handler/http=firefox.desktop
x-scheme-handler/https=firefox.desktop
x-scheme-handler/ftp=firefox.desktop
x-scheme-handler/chrome=firefox.desktop
text/html=sublime.desktop
application/x-extension-htm=sublime.desktop
application/x-extension-html=sublime.desktop
application/x-extension-shtml=firefox.desktop
application/xhtml+xml=firefox.desktop
application/x-extension-xhtml=firefox.desktop
application/x-extension-xht=firefox.desktop

[Added Associations]
x-scheme-handler/http=firefox.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/https=firefox.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/ftp=firefox.desktop;
x-scheme-handler/chrome=firefox.desktop;
application/x-extension-htm=firefox.desktop;
application/x-extension-html=firefox.desktop;
application/x-extension-shtml=firefox.desktop;
application/xhtml+xml=firefox.desktop;
application/x-extension-xhtml=firefox.desktop;
application/x-extension-xht=firefox.desktop;
application/x-yaml=sublime-1.desktop;

[Removed Associations]
text/html=firefox.desktop;gedit.desktop;
```

You can of-course change as many or as little as you want and you can also add as many or as little as you want to the desktop files MimeType for example `application/python`, `application/x-ruby`, `text/ruby`, `text/x-python` or dozens of other variants... though sticking to simple types should be alright for example `application/python` and `application/ruby` both work on my GNOME 3.2 install.

Answer (score 6):

In newer versions of Gnome, you don't need to manually edit anything now.  Right-click on the file you want to open, select Properties, go to the Open With tab, and select the default application you want to use...then click "Set as default".

Answer (score 4):

gnome-panel still has the old gnome2 command to do this.

Enter:

```
gnome-desktop-item-edit ~/.local/share/applications/ --create-new
```

Then use `your-command %U` as the command.

Comment: Thanks Steve, surely that is another way, albeit less viable. By the way you can also pull out that panel from `alacarte`

Answer (score 0):

In Gnome 3.4.2 there is another way to change defaults for web, mail, calendar, music, video and photos.
You have to use the gnome-control-center (or Details in Activities menu). Then go to --> Default Applications

Comment: Thank you for your answer, although that is not what I was asking. I wanted to change the default application for an arbitrary file type other than web, music etc.

Answer (score -2):

I believe you can modify the entries in this file: `/usr/share/gnome/applications/defaults.list`.

Comment: How does this answer the question?  What should one do with this file?  On what systems does changing this file apply (on my Fedora 19 with gnome 3.8, this file doesn't exist)?

Comment: This file doesn't exist on my Fedora 19 GNOME 3 install, so I don't think it's correct advice.